# Como criar uma arrayList em clojure

Tags: clojure

Como criar uma arrayList em clojure e adicionar elementos? (a existente em java)

Meu problema é o seguinte: Preciso ler um arquivo e ir adicionando substrings desse arquivo (delimitadas por espaço e quebra de linha "\n"), como elementos separados nessa arrayList.

Consigo ler, delimitar os espaços, porém não consigo importar o modo de declarar arrayList do java e não sei como faze-lo.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o [split-lines](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.string/split-lines) para fazer tudo de uma vez só:

```
(:require string :as string]))
  (string/split-lines "1\n2\n3") ; resultado: ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Para criar um arrayList em clojure, faça conforme abaixo:

```
user=> (def newlist '(1 2 3))
```

lembrando que, `newlist` é o nome que eu defini para a lista, é necessario usar `'` no inicio, ou trocar `'` por `(list 1 2 3)`

Para adicionar elementos a lista utilize:

```
user=> (conj newlist 4)
```

No exemplo acima, adicionei o elemento 4 na `newlist`, tendo como retorno:

```
(4 1 2 3)
```

A função `conj` adiciona o elemento no inicio da lista, é a mesma coisa que usar `cons`, porém é mais eficiente.

fonte: https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/pt-br/clojure-pt/ editado pelo autor.